# How to get Product Price by ID

Tags: magento2, price

I am getting product using the below code but it is not returning the exact price displayed on product

[image]

My code for getting price

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
 $productData['price']= $product->getPrice();
```

Comment: What type of product is it?

Comment: It's a simple product

Comment: I wan't to get the price that is displayed on product , i don't have any custom block I am returung the price using controller

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom block and call it in my controller

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

class Price extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    protected $_product;
    protected $_layout;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
    ) {
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_layout = $layout;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
        if (!$priceRender) {
            $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
                'product.price.render.default',
                ['data' => ['price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices']]
            );
        }
    
        $price = '';
        if ($priceRender) {
            $price = $priceRender->render(
                \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                $product,
                [
                    'display_minimal_price'  => true,
                    'use_link_for_as_low_as' => true,
                    'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST
                ]
            );
        }
    
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Call it in controller

```
$blockInstance = $this->_objectManager->get('Vendor\Module\Block\Product\Price');
$productData['price']= $blockInstance->getPrice($product);
```